# General audience books that teach deep mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

When I was younger some of my favorite books were Raymond Smullyan's puzzle books. He strove to write books that covered topics more deep than more standard children's puzzles; [To Mock a Mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird) gets into serious thought about [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), and [Forever Undecided](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192801414), an introduction to Godel's incompleteness theorem, phrasing everything in terms of the classic children's puzzles about people who always lie and people who always tell the truth. (For a much shorter but higher-brow sample of what the writing looks like, [he has a brief note about roughly the same subject](http://www.tark.org/proceedings/tark_mar19_86/p341-smullyan.pdf).) I recently looked at them again, and they still hold up (or maybe are even made better) looking back at them with an actual math education.

What I would like are books that are accessible to a general audience - especially kids! - that nonetheless are able to introduce one to nontrivial, deep mathematics, like Smullyan's books above. I would prefer books that actually teach the mathematics (however disguised) as opposed to something like Simon Singh's expository book on [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_(book)) (which tells you the story of FLT, but nothing about the mathematics behind it.)

Comment: That's quite a paper.  It reminds me of the [ten-year-long, 35 page argument about the solution to the "Blue Eyes" puzzle](http://fora.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3), except that the paper you refer to is the opposite—it's like a breath of fresh air.  :)

Answer (score 4):

- I recommended Conway et al.'s [*Symmetries of Things*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812205) in a recent answer, and I'll do it again!

Essentially, the first third of the book is devoted to two-dimensional symmetry, and is generally very layperson-friendly, with lots of good pictures and things that utilize intuition. Generally the first 100 pages should be doable for anybody with a genuine interest. The next 100 pages are a bit more difficult, and then abstract groups are encountered, at which point all bets are off (but to be fair, it's still a pretty gentle treatment!). So, maybe it's not a very good fit for *young* children, but I'd say ages 10-12+ should be able to get plenty out of it. It doesn't hide the fact that it's a book about math, whatever that means.

- And while I realize this isn't a book, [Satyan Devadoss](http://satyandevadoss.org/) has a series of video lectures about quality mathematics for a general audience, called [The Shape of Nature](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/shape-of-nature.html). It's not cheap, but I managed to borrow a copy through an interlibrary loan and it was well worth it.

Answer (score 3):

In Russia, those 2 books were very popular:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Fun-Yakov-Perelman/dp/2917260262/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450470498&sr=8-1&keywords=perelman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2917260262)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Entertainment-Yakov-Perelman-ebook/dp/B00MVB5PRY/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1450470498&sr=8-2&keywords=perelman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MVB5PRY)

not sure how their english translation compares to the original Russian though